# Lua table.insert not working

Tags: lua

So I just want to insert a value into a table I defined, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

If I use this code:

```
t = {1,2,3}
table.insert(t, 9)
```

all i get is

> LuaInterface.LuaScriptException: [string "main"]:2: attempt to call
>   field 'insert' (a nil value)

Is it possible that I'm using a compiler that just doesn't have this function? I really don't get it. I'm using the BizHawk Emulator for compiling right now if that matters.

Comment: Try `require("table").insert(t, 9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does by chance get "table" or "table.insert" get overwritten somewhere previously in the code? Or maybe the table library was not loaded?

Try

```
require("table")
```

prior to the call to table.insert and see if it works then

Comment: If global variable `table` was overwritten, then `require("table")` would be not enough to recover it.

Comment: Correct, package.loaded["table"] = nil had to be performed first (for lua 5.2, otherwise _LOADED["table"] = nil)

Comment: Thank you, "require("table")" worked!
Since the code posted above was the only code in the entire file I'm pretty sure nothing has been overwritten. So I guess the emulator is using an old version of LUA.

Comment: It is also possible that the lua does not open the libraries by default for performance reasons. For example opening debug library can be useless if not debugging. Opening default libraries has to be coded specifically and is not done automatically if a lua state is created.

Comment: @Rochet2 Yea, but `require` and `package` are also not loaded by default either.